# Get total block device IO from kernel including buffer cache hits

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, proc

I'm working on creating a tool to display system stats on Linux. I'm using the /sys and /proc APIs for this to learn how they work.

Currently, I'm reading `/sys/block/<dev>/stat` to get block device statistics ([docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt)). This works great for seeing how much reading and writing is happening on disk, but I'm wondering if it is possible to see the total block device I/O from an application's perspective.

Here's an example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
> cat somebigfile > /dev/zero # Takes some time, triggers device I/O
> cat somebigfile > /dev/zero # Runs quickly a second time, no device I/O
```

I believe the difference between the two runs is due to the kernel going to the buffer cache rather than the disk for the second read. I have confirmed this by flushing the cache using `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` causing the command to execute like the first time again.

**What is the easiest way to see the total bytes read from block devices, including bytes served from the buffer cache, over some time period?**

I have also considering summing the values in `/proc/<pid>/io`, but this includes all I/O and isn't split out by device or type.

I am aware that I could do this using something like [System Tap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/), but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 'stat collector' service several years ago - [rwdisk_stat](https://github.com/lnkgyv/rwdisk_stat).

I used values in `/sys/block/<dev>/stat` and then converted their in bytes.

From application perspective, **cgroups** is useful. It's possible to put distinguish application in some group '[blkio](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt)' and read 'blkio.io_service_bytes' counter.

Comment: Thanks for that. That sounds like what I am doing currently. In your case, you were measuring bytes actually read/written to disk. I'd like to do this but also include bytes that applications read/write to "disk", but that were actually served by the buffer cache.